# Select first element in list starting from sibling

Tags: jquery

Starting from `$('#selected')`, what would be the best way to select the first list item?

```
<ul>
 <li>first</li>
 <li>second</li>
 <li id="selected">third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it fails to show any research attempt.

Comment: Where's your jQuery? What have you tried?  Show us your code so we can help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard.  I could do it using `parent()` and `find()`, but why show this as it clearly isn't the best way to do so.

Comment: @user1032531 If your question is "is there a better/cleaner way to get the first of a list of siblings than .parent().find(), that's okay!  Knowing where you are in the process of finding a solution helps us better tailor answers to the needs of your problem.

Comment: You should have stated that in the question which would have made your intent clearer.

Comment: I think Felix's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** along with **[.first()](http://api.jquery.com/first/)** or **[:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)** selector:

```
$('#selected').siblings('li:first') // or $('#selected').siblings('li').first()
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yY6a2/)**

Comment: Thanks Felix, I've never used `siblings` before, and didn't even know it existed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selected').parentNode.children[0]
```

or

```
$('#selected').parentNode.firstChild
```

are both options, despite not being all jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

try this one

```
$('#selected').parent().children('li')[0];
```